# Could not find a declaration for module 'mssql/msnodesqlv8'

Tags: sql-server, node.js

developing `API` using `typescript` in `node.js`

importing the below package to use `sql server database`

```
import sql from "mssql/msnodesqlv8";
```

but this giving me the following error

> Could not find a declaration for module 'mssql/msnodesqlv8'
>       implicitly has an any type. if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file 
>       containing declare module 'mssql'

I have this declaration in almost every routing file and facing this ugly red color on every file showing me error because of this declaration.

The following packages are installed in my project

```
"msnodesqlv8": "^0.6.6",
"mssql": "^4.1.0",
"@types/mssql": "^4.0.7",
```

Any suggestions to get out of this?

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I have done the same but still not working for me either

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by running :
npm install mssql & npm install msnodesqlv8

my package.json look like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wMTk.png

connect to SQL Server and run query :

```js
  const connection = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    server: *ServerName* ,
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    options: {
      trustedConnection: true
    }})

  connection.connect().then(()=> {
    connection.query(`*Query*`,(err,result)=>{
      if(err){
        res.send(err);
      }
      else{
        res.json(result)
      }
    })
})
```

Comment: Can u share how u did the above one, i mean the connection and imports